# How do I show a previously hidden div if the view port is resized?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, show-hide

I am developing a responsive site using Bootstrap 3. I have a JS show/hide script which is available when the screen is `max-width 767px`, but if I have shown and then hidden the div in that size, when I resize the screen back to desktop the div is still hidden.

Is there away to force the div to come back if the screen goes beyond a `767px`?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showFunction() {
        document.getElementById("left-col").style.visibility="visible";
    }

    function hideFunction() {
        document.getElementById("left-col").style.visibility="hidden";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Provide code examples please

Comment: I am just using a basic getElementbyID and changing the display to none or block and the target is using the class visible-xs so that it is only visible at max-width767px i need something to reset the divs style with the screensize being the event?

Comment: why can't you just do both with css media queries?

Comment: Is this possible? I am using the media query to hide the div when in xs (mobile size) but then I am using the show and hide to over lay the div over the main content area. The issue I am experiencing is when I hide it onclick and then change the screen side to desktop the div still remains hidden. I want to be able to show and hide when the screen isnt big enough to include it but then for the script to reset when the screen size changes.

Comment: You need to post your code. If your "I am just using a basic getElementbyID...", then post what you are "just using"!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  function showFunction()
  {
  document.getElementById("left-col").style.visibility="visible";
  }
  function hideFunction()
  {
  document.getElementById("left-col").style.visibility="hidden";
  }
</script> this is the show and hide code which I am using on the button which is visible in mobile view.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a media query then?

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .left-col {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9y1s14o/

Comment: Hi let me start again - I have a left-col div which is a left col in desktop view but in mobile view I am hiding it using the media query. But am wanting to display the left-col when clicking a button in mobile - so that it acts like a slide in menu with the width 75% of the screen this is fine I have this working. But if I minimise the browser to mobile size then click 'show' left col (This works) then click close the left-col (hide it) when I change the browser size back to desktop the left-col remains hidden which I don't want. I want it to bring it back in even if it has been hidden.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two ways to do this:

1. Use CSS to force the div to be shown at one size, and hidden at another
2. Use JavaScript to listen for changes in the browser and then call a function to modify the state of the dom

With CSS, you tell the browser what to do when the window is bigger than your breakpoint, and what to do when your window is smaller than your breakpoint, which `767 px`.

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .left-col {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .left-col {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

With JavaScript, you tell the browser to call a function when the window resizes:

```
var breakpoint = 767;
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (window.innerWidth >= breakpoint) {
       showFunction();
    } else { 
       hideFunction();
    }
};
```

Note: Your specifics might be slightly different, but this is meant to illustrate the idea behind it. Tweak the details that you need to.